# Unable to input value in structure

Tags: c, struct, structure

```
struct student{
    char name[20]; /* student name */
    double testScore; /* test score */
    double examScore; /* exam score */
    double total; /* total score = test+exam scores */
};

void computeScore(student information);
int main()
{
struct student information[50];
                for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                {
                    printf("Enter the student name: ");
                    gets(information[i].name);
                    printf("\nEnter test score: ");
                    scanf("%lf",information[i].testScore);
                    printf("\nEnter exam score: ");
                    scanf("%lf",information[i].examScore);
                    computeScore(information[i]);
                }
}
```

I tried entering the input Test Score but directly after Test Score my program terminate. Any ideas? It does not even reach the Enter exam score.

Comment: scanf("%lf",&information[i].testScore); pass the address

Comment: and the same for examScore.

Comment: Please don't use `gets()`, even in toy code.  It is no longer a part of standard C.  It is impossible for a program using `gets()` to defend itself against abuse. If your compiler wasn't warning about the mismatch between the `scanf()` format and the actual arguments, you either need to turn on more compilation warnings or you need to get a better compiler.  If you use GCC, add `-Wall -Werror` as a good start; add `-Wextra` for preference.  I use even fussier options — and my code compiles cleanly.

Comment: so is it better to use scanf("%s",&information[i].name) ?

Comment: No; it is incorrect to use `scanf("%s", &information[i].name)` — that passes a different type (`char (*)[20]` instead of `char *`) to `scanf()`.  It actually works in this context because the byte value of the addresses are the same, but the types are technically different.  Use `scanf("%s", information[i].name)`.

Comment: Also `i` is not declared you must turn on your compiler warnings..

Comment: Our you post code that went through the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of the variable *information*, which is a object to the structure "student", in which you defined variables as "double". It means an error was found when the program tried to read a value for double data type using a to structure.

Borland's compilers do not link in the floating-point (f-p) library unless we need it. Therefore, by force we need to add any floating-point (f-p) function when we have "%f" or other floating point (f-p) formats in scanf() or printf() calls.

> void dummy(double*a) {
>
> double b=*a; //perform some floating access
>
> dummy (&b);  //calling a floating point function
>
> }

Just only add this function in your program.